# Delete Users and Separate User and Groups

Tags: user-account

I am using a Mac for both personal and work and want to keep them separate as I can. I think a good solution would be for me to have 2 users -- a personal and work user -- but the only problem is when I download software in my personal account it appears in my work user account. Luckily I caught this early enough I could just delete my work user, but can't seem to be able to do that.

How do I delete a user? How do I keep the user profiles separate so what I download in one doesn't show up in the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, if you download something (apps, files, anything): it is saved in your User account's Download folder.

When applications arrive, it is usual to copy or install them into the root level `/Applications` folder. This location is accessible to all users.

If you want applications to be available to only one user, then move them to `<user>/Applications`. You may need to create this folder inside your user account.

Comment: This worked perfectly! only problem is I don't know how to change my App Store settings to only install `<user>/Applications` folder. Is there a way to do that or do I just need to constantly move them over?

Comment: @TylerStrouth no, there's no setting (that I know of) to  install App Store apps in the user account. You'll just have to move them over. Usually, it's the user data that needs to be separate, and it's not a problem if you have games or lifestyle apps accessible from your work account -- as long as you don't user them on the company's time!

Answer (score 1):

Install the apps you want to use as both users in ~/Public. This works even for users without administrator rights.