# Allowing standard users to update apps

Tags: software-update

thank you to anyone who can potentially assist. Is anyone familiar with a way that I can allow certain apps to be updated by standard users? For example, Zoom updates requires an administrator to authenticate before it updates. This spans to other applications too that we constantly get tickets requesting software to be updated. Apple support shut it down completely, however I'm not convinced.

We are running Catalina.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396189/22769

Answer (score 3):

The user can install the app in a folder in their own home directory, which makes it possible for them to update it.

The main /Applications folder is for system-wide applications, where it makes sense that only Administrator users can change them.